# How to convert pandas data frame datetime column to int?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, type-conversion

I am facing an issue while converting one of my `datetime` columns in [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe) to `int.` My code is:

```
df['datetime_column'].astype(np.int64)
```

The error which I am getting is:

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2018-02-25 09:31:15'

I am quite clueless about what is happening as the conversion for some of my other `datetime` columns are working fine. Is there some issue with the range of the date which can be converted to `int`?

Comment: What integer do you expect that '2018-02-25 09:31:15' be converted to?

Comment: It seemed to me as well that the values are out of range. But when I tried to convert them to 'float' , I got the following error:

    could not convert string to float: '2018-02-15 14:28:08'

I guess I forgot to convert the column to 'datetime' before converting it to 'int'.

I updated the code as:
    
    'pd.to_datetime(df['datetime_column']).astype(np.int64)'

and the conversion is working fine.

Comment: Why would you convert datetime to int by casting? Don’t you want df['date_time'].map(dt.datetime.toordinal) instead?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. 
I am building a decision tree model and need to extract some features from the datetime field. I have extracted month, year, day, day of the week, hour of the day, weekend indicator, offset from current date etc. I am just experimenting by adding new features and hence doing a conversion simply by casting.

By the way,  datetime.toordinal and offset from the current date should be correlated, I guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you solved the problem yourself judging from your comment.  My guess is that you created the data frame without specifying that the column should be read as anything other than a string, so it's a string.  If I'm right, and you check the column type, it should show as object.  If you check an individual entry in the column, it should show as a string.

If the issue is something else, please follow up.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

You would use

```
df['datetime_colum'].apply(lambda x:x.toordinal())
```

If it fails, the cause could be that your column is an object and not datetime. So you need:

```
df['datetime_colum'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime_colum'])
```

before sending it to ordinal.

If you are working on features engineering, you can try creating days between date1 and date2, get boolean for if it is winter, summer, autumn or spring by looking at months, and if you have time, boolean of if it is morning, noontime, or night, but all depending on your machines learning problem.